# MySQL SELECT NOT IN from 30K rows fast

Tags: mysql, sql, select, cpu-usage

My DB table name_info has it 30K row & terms table 60K row, When select not in table, server CPU goes up.

How can I best write a query that select 1 row fast?

```
SELECT slug FROM terms WHERE slug LIKE 'nm%' AND slug NOT IN 
(SELECT imdb_id FROM name_info) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What data type is slug and immdb_id?

Comment: String/varchar like nm1084488

Comment: Try joining terms to name_info with an outer join on name.info.imdb_id and terms.slug.  The join will probably perform better than the subselect.

Comment: Listen to @LornaMitchell. MySQL executes joins faster than the NOT IN sub-query construction.

Comment: Thank you, with @sloan-thrasher code work perfectly, exactly yours solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the columns used in the query are indexed.

```
SELECT `slug`
FROM `terms` 
LEFT JOIN `name_info`
ON `slug` = `imdb_id`
WHERE slug LIKE 'nm%' 
AND `imdb_id` IS NULL
LIMIT 0,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use not exists

```
SELECT slug FROM terms WHERE slug LIKE 'nm%' AND not exists
(SELECT 1 FROM name_info where imdb_id = slug) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Vecchiasignora, but behavior like my sql code